# How to set repeating top 2 rows as headers when printing an excel worksheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am very new to Python and am experimenting with creating and printing excel spreadsheets. Just for the record, I have many years of experience in C and C++ programming. I am using Python 3.5.1 and OpenPyxl on Windows 7 and working with xlsx files.The code snippet I am using to repeat top 2 rows as repeating page headers is reproduced below:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook  import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.properties import WorksheetProperties
...
sheet.print_options.gridLines = True
sheet.print_title_rows = '1:2'  #**problem code not working as intended**
sheet.page_setup.orientation = sheet.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
...
```

All other settings above are working as expected except for the assignment statement to print_title_rows in the active worksheet. I will be immensely grateful to gurus on this board if  they can point me in the right direction. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

```
ws.print_title_cols = 'A:B' # the first two cols
ws.print_title_rows = '1:2' # the first two rows
```

Also, `sheet.add_print_title(2)` is deprecated since 2.4.0-a1 (2016-04-11).

**Viewing the output file:** at least in LibreOffice 6.0 the rows/columns are not repeated. Works fine in MS Excel 2013 though. [Bug #973](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/973/print-titles-print_title_rows-does-not)

source: [openpyxl documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/print_settings.html?highlight=print%20title)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sheet.print_title_rows = '1:2'
```

with

```
sheet.add_print_title(2)
```

You can also repeat columns using 'cols' as the second argument of the method.

See the official documentation
[add_print_title(n, rows_or_cols='rows')](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.add_print_title)